# How to delete a nested array in mongodb collection with node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multidimensional-array

### I'm trying to delete "627cfc7a9765ad8c65d03798" in 'Rooms'

**obje:**

```
    _id:627b93d43c14903de411d915
    name:"Awesome Hotel Updated"
    type:"hotel"
    city:"berlin"
    tittle:"Best Hotel in the City"
    rooms:[
     0:"627cf8c384aa07450d629279"
     1:"627cfc7a9765ad8c65d03798"
    ]
```

**function :**

```
    export const deleteRoom = async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            await Room.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
            await Hotel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.hotelId, {
                $pull: { rooms: req.params.id }
            })
            res.status(200).json("Room has been deleted.");
        } catch (err) {
            next(err)
        }
    }
```

Help me delete items in 'Rooms'!

Comment: please share, what issue is fetching that?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for this:

```
const object = {
     _id:627b93d43c14903de411d915,
    name:"Awesome Hotel Updated",
    type:"hotel",
    city:"berlin",
    tittle:"Best Hotel in the City",
    rooms:[
     {room_id:"627cf8c384aa07450d629279"},
     {room_id:"627cfc7a9765ad8c65d03798"}
    ]
}
```

Here in this "object" you should store your room id as above mentioned "**room_id**",
So this will help you to filter your rooms easy

Instead Try this:

```
  export const deleteRoom = async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            const room = await Room.findById(req.params.id);
            const hotel = await Hotel.findById(req.params.hotelId)
            await room.remove()
            hotel.rooms.splice(hotel.rooms.findIndex(a => a.room_id === room.id) , 1)
            

            res.status(200).json("Room has been deleted.");
        } catch (err) {
            next(err)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code does work.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "city": "berlin"
},
{
  $pull: {
    "rooms": "627cf8c384aa07450d629279"
  }
})
```

Maybe you're getting an error somewhere inside the `findByIdAndUpdate` method